# Get link_id by object_id

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-fql

How can I get link_id by object_id through FQL or OpenGraph ? 
I'm trying exequte this query:

```
FB.api('fql', {
    'q'     : '{'+
        '"object_url":"SELECT id, url,type FROM object_url WHERE url IN (SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id=me())",' +                            
        '"link":"SELECT link_id, url FROM link WHERE link_id IN (SELECT id FROM #object_url WHERE type=\\\"link\\\")",' +                
    '}'
},
```

But link_id is not the same as object_url.id